# Compass sprite background position is not as i want it

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm first-time using Compass spriting. I wanted to have icons images (all are in little different in sizes) centered position. like the attached image

[image]

I'm using this setting

```
$icons-spacing:40px;
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

the css i'm getting is (for example)

```
.icons-adventure {
  background-position: 0 -608px;
}
```

It's not that as I required. I want to give more spacing from top and left.

Comment: Can you show me the "I want this" example in plain CSS ?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out this Github Gist: https://gist.github.com/adamlogic/3577147, which has helped me fix spriting issues in the past and also gain a better understanding of how spriting in Compass works.

Of particular interest to you may be the portion where the author mentions the following: (pasted here in case the Gist is removed)

> "I took this a bit further by defining my own (sprite) mixin."

```
$spritemap-spacing: 50px
@import "spritemap/*.png"

=background-sprite($name, $repeat: no-repeat, $offset-x: 0, $offset-y: 0)
  background-image: $spritemap-sprites
  background-repeat: $repeat
  +sprite-background-position($spritemap-sprites, $name, $offset-x, $offset-y)

  // if no offsets given, set the dimensions of the element to match the image
  @if $offset-x == 0 and $offset-y == 0
    +sprite-dimensions($spritemap-sprites, $name)
```

> "and how I'm using it"

```
// simplest case; sets the background image and dimensions of the element
h3
  +background-sprite(ribbonfull)

// custom offset; does not set the dimensions of the element
h2
  +background-sprite(ribbonend, no-repeat, 3px, 22px)

// repeating backgrounds are possible, too
#positions
  +background-sprite(doubleline, repeat-x, 0, 45px)
```

And, the author's generated CSS:

```
h3 {
  background-image: url('/images/spritemap-sb826ca2aba.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -405px;
  height: 29px;
  width: 295px; }

h2 {
  background-image: url('/images/spritemap-sb826ca2aba.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 3px -296px; }

#positions {
  background-image: url('/images/spritemap-sb826ca2aba.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 -751px; }
```

Comment: I think this is the most useful answer here. Thanks a lot - it's no native compass function, but it does what's been asked for in this topic.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve found two workarounds for this issue, both not perfect:

1. You can simply save the icon in your image editor with the necessary padding - it works if you want to use it only in one place, otherwise you have to create duplicates (which is why this doesn't always work).
2. Other solution is to use pseudoelements. Assuming  is the element you want to add the background to and you’ve placed your icons in icons folder:

> ```
> @import "icons/*.png";
>
> el { 
>   position: relative; 
> }
>
> el:after { 
>   content: ""; 
>   position: absolute; 
>   left: 50%; 
>   top: 50%; 
>   @include icons-sprite(some_icon); 
>   margin-top: - round(icons-sprite-height(some_icon) / 2); 
>   margin-left: - round(icons-sprite-width(some_icon) / 2);    
> }
> ```

Comment: I also came across the pseudo elements solution. This only works for containers, though, and not for e.g. input fields.

Answer (score 1):

`$icons-spacing` defines the number of pixels that separates each image in the generated sprite map. I believe you want to adjust the `$icons-position` which adjusts (offsets) the generated `background-position` styles

Comment: how to give vertical icon position?

Comment: vertical icon positioning doesn't seem to be available. But take a look at ctrlaltdel's answer, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a good question...

When you give sprites in CSS, you will be able to generate classes with the `.image-name`. And this is how Compass sprites work. Your image will be appended to a big sprite image, and all the irregular images will be clubbed together in a grid manner.

Even though `$icons-spacing` gives you the ability to give some padding to the grid, it won't be that easy for you to put it in this case. So, going ahead with what is generated, we will do the following.

So, if you want something like the picture, you need to center the element, which has the Compass generated class.

Now say, you have `adventure.png` in it and it has generated this class:

```
.icons-adventure {
    background-position: 0 -608px;
}
```

Now, if you want to make this centered, you can make this way.

```
<div class="border">
    <i class="icons-adventure"></i>
</div>
```

And for the `border` class, give padding. So, what I mean here is, you have wrapped the `.border` on the `.icons-adventure`. Now, you need to give some padding and width to it.

```
.border {padding: 15px; width: 40px;}
```

Here, there's is no need of height, as the height is automatically taken care. Let me come with a fiddle for you to get a clear explanation.

Comment: I don't want to add extra div elements to just to center the sprite. I know I can do this manually without extra div but wanted to know how to get it using compass.

Comment: @JitendraVyas Only [these](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/customization-options/) are the possible values you can customize using Compass. The best value would be `$icons-spacing`.

Comment: Yes I know $icons-spacing but it's only for horizontal spacing. previous has also mentioned this

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of your icon you could set a default height for all icons and give single icons an vertical offset of (default height - icon height)/2 and position horizontal with center:

```
$sprite-spacing: 50px;
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "sprite/*.png";
@include all-sprite-sprites;
$sprite: sprite-map("sprite/*.png", $spacing: 50px);

@include sprite-sprite(myicon);
@include sprite-background-position($sprite, myicon, center, 12px);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 just use the following code, its simple and clean,

SASS File

```
@import "compass";
$home-spacing : 10px;
$home-sprite-dimensions : true;
@import "web/images/home/*.png";
@include all-home-sprites;
```

And in the HTML/Slim File I just use the `center-block` provided by Twitter Bootstrap 3, My HTML helper,

```
=content_tag('div','',:class=>'home-save_money center-block')
```

Basically it just center align the images into the center of the div, all the answer above use some custom Mixins or a hack.

PS: Even if you dont use twitter bootstrap, just use the following CSS, that would do the trick,

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

I hope this helps some one,